# Entity Framework two composite foreign key to same table, backref relation not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two classes

```cs
public class AuctionModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual UserModel Seller { get; set; }
    public string SellerUsername { get; set; }
    public string SellerSiteName { get; set; }

    public string CurrentWinnerUsername { get; set; }
    public string CurrentWinnerSiteName { get; set; }
    public virtual UserModel CurrentWinner { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
    public class UserModel : Base
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string SiteName { get; set; }

    public virtual SiteModel Site { get; set; }

    public List<AuctionModel> Auctions { get; set; }
    public List<AuctionModel> WinningAuctions { get; set; } 
}
```

And the Fluent Api specify the relations as

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<AuctionModel>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Seller)
            .WithMany(u => u.Auctions)
            .HasForeignKey(a => new {a.SellerUsername, a.SellerSiteName});

        modelBuilder.Entity<AuctionModel>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.CurrentWinner)
            .WithMany(u => u.WinningAuctions)
            .HasForeignKey(a => new {a.CurrentWinnerSiteName, a.CurrentWinnerUsername});
    }
```

From what i know, this should work correctly, but what really happens is that UserModel.Auctions and CurrentModel.WinningAuctions are always null. I know that the object are attached because i checked and the relations are null even just after i save the object on the database.

Update:

```
return context.Users.Include("MyAuctions").Include("WinningAuctions").First(u => u.Username == userName && u.SiteName == siteName);
```

Loading data with Includes, loads the relation. This is somewhat to be expected, but even if i changes relations into

```
    public virtual List<AuctionModel> MyAuctions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AuctionModel> WinningAuctions { get; set; }
```

I still have to use Include or i get null. And this really doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Shouldn't the SiteName go first in the FK, since it's first in the column order?

Comment: I tried to switch FK order, but nope, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem war simply that the two collections should have been ICollection<> instead of IList<>

Answer (score 2):

This happens because this is the way that you are telling to EF that load the data. To load the Auctions and WinningAuctions properties, you need to specifify that you want include then explicity using the `Include` method (this is called Eagerly Loading):

```
var usertest = db.Users.Include(u => u.WinningAuctions).Include(u => u.Auctions).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == "Albert" && u.SiteName == "localhost");
```

If you change your collection properties as `virtual` you don't need to do the Includes.

```
public class UserModel
{
    public virtual List<AuctionModel> Auctions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AuctionModel> WinningAuctions { get; set; }
}
```

Any virtual Collections will be lazy-loaded unless you specifically mark them otherwise.

If you want to learn more about how EF load data and how you can configurate this, check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx).

### Update

If still does not work the lazy loading behavior, you need to check if you model classes satisfy the conditions that need EF to create the proxy classes. Take a look this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: OP's question is that the entities are not found at all on the collections. The type of loading doesn't matter if nothing is being brought back.

Comment: The first part works (sorry for the downvote, i will correct this in next 18 hours), but the second does not!

I cannot uderstand why, from what i read in the document you linked, it should.

Comment: do you know if you have enable the lazy loading behavior? It works in my test project

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not entirely sure how to solve this with the Fluent API, but here's how you would do it with Data Annotations:

```
public class AuctionModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Seller"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public string SellerUsername { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Seller"), Column(Order = 3)]
    public string SellerSiteName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurrentWinner"), Column(Order = 4)]
    public string CurrentWinnerUsername { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurrentWinner"), Column(Order = 5)]
    public string CurrentWinnerSiteName { get; set; }

    public virtual UserModel Seller { get; set; }
    public virtual UserModel CurrentWinner { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello @IronMan84, are you sure that his model configuration doesn't work? I created some users an later some auctions, and the relationships created between the two entities are working and persisted in the database.

Comment: They may or may not work, I don't know. I haven't spent that much time toying with the Fluent API, which is why I posted how to do it in Data Annotations.

Comment: For that reason is that I suggest in my answer to take into account the way that EF load the data. I test with some data using the Includes and It works

Comment: But not using `Include` won't make the collection be null. `Include` only tells EF to load the entities right away.

Comment: but why if I use the Includes load the properties and when I remove them don't

Comment: I think this happens because the two navegation properties (Autions and WinningAuctions) are not virtual.